# more fields on a content type or more content types

Tags: entities, nodes

I know this is a situational/subjective question..... but I am trying to figure out a site architecture for a drupal site.

I have multiple products with different attributes/properties. I could either make one content type called 'products' with multiple fields for all possible attributes ..... or I could could make multiple content types; one for each type of product.

I am just looking for a 'best practice' kind of answer.

should I make one content type with more fields (that may go unused more often)

....

or should I make more content types.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference is to limit the amount of content types, for user friendly reasons. Clients can get confused when you throw a whole list of content types at them. Unless your products are very different to each other (car, washing machine, house), I'd go for the fields.

Maybe the [Field Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) can help to keep things tidy in the backend part of a product node.

Answer (score 0):

I also tend to prefer using less content types, assumed products have not a dramatically distinct set of fields.

I agree that the module @cptstarling suggested should be useful, but at the same time seems it may be a bit heavy for your need.
So in the other hand you could also look at [Conditional field](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module, which is quite simpler.